# angular-wizard: How to set step2 (or 3,4,..) instead step 1 on form load?

Tags: angularjs, wizard

I have a form with angular-wizard steps like below

```
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" edit-mode="false" indicators-position="top" current-step="currentStep">
    <wz-step wz-title="Unqualified">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
                <label class="control-label">Source Lead</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="source_lead"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="New">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
                <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="company" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Working">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
                <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="title" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Nurturing">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
                <label class="control-label">Rating</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="rating" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Converted">

    </wz-step>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" wz-next ng-click="StepCompleted(currentStep)">Completed</button>
    </div>
</wizard>
```

I want to focus to the step "New" (or "Working", or "Converted",...) instead step "Unqualified" on form load.

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want previous than current steps visited or not?

Comment: @tanmay, this is plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/A1sZLGVE4b6jiGZVLWF3?p=preview

Comment: I set currentStep="Working", and I want focus to Working step on form load

Comment: yes, I know that, do you want previous than `working` step visited?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean @@. My english is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do. In their [**`WizardHandler`** service](https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard#manipulating-the-wizard-from-a-service), we have access to functions like `goTo()` (on `wizard()` which is your current wizard). Like this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    WizardHandler.wizard().goTo("Working");
});
```

**Why inside `$timeout`**?

**Because**, if the second parameter to `$timeout` i.e. `delay` is not provided, the default behaviour is to execute the function after the DOM has completed rendering.

And, we need to execute this after wizard completes rendering.

Here's the [**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6hiWHgdoQwwq3Aji7jX2?p=preview)

***Alternatively***, if you want the previous steps to be visited (*visited steps look green with default styles*), you can write a loop that goes `next()` until we reach our desired step (in this case, `Working`)

Answer (score 2):

Change their position, if you want step "New" to be first, just set it as first.

```
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" edit-mode="false" indicators-position="top" current-step="currentStep">
<wz-step wz-title="New">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
            <label class="control-label">Company</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="company" />
        </div>
    </div>
</wz-step>
<wz-step wz-title="Unqualified">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
            <label class="control-label">Source Lead</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="source_lead"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</wz-step>
<wz-step wz-title="Working">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
            <label class="control-label">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="title" />
        </div>
    </div>
</wz-step>
<wz-step wz-title="Nurturing">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 remove_padding">
            <label class="control-label">Rating</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm clearable" ng-model="rating" />
        </div>
    </div>
</wz-step>
<wz-step wz-title="Converted">

</wz-step>
<div class="panel-body">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" wz-next ng-click="StepCompleted(currentStep)">Completed</button>
</div>
```

Or you can set `wz-order` attribute. The is order in which the steps should be in. If no order or duplicated order it will add the step to the end.

Comment: I try that, but not working. You can see my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/A1sZLGVE4b6jiGZVLWF3?p=preview

Comment: you can try attribute wz-order .The order in which the steps should be in. If no order or duplicated order it will add the step to the end.